# If not CPU, disk or network, what is the bottleneck during query execution?

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows

I work with SQL Server 2005 and wonder, if not CPU, disk or network, what are users waiting for when SQL Server is working. The strange thing is that system monitor shows that the 4 processors are at an average of 5%, the disk (demonstrated 50MB/s write) works with about 5-8 MB/s, but the execution (inserts and selects) take up to 10 minutes. I'd be happy to install additional hardware, but I don't see what device is the bottleneck and how do I measure its capacity and current workload.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

additional info: RAM is constantly at about 70% capacity and I am running windows xp.

Comment: With disks remember that sequential (all the blocks are together) will be vastly better than random (blocks scattered over the disk: lots of head movement and waiting for the platter to spin).

Comment: Which edition of SQL server 2005 are you using?

Comment: @niktrs I use the Standard Edition..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your disk read and write 'wait' time. a heavy load database may just make a lot of read and write request with very small piece of data that saturates the IO.

Comment: wow! didn't expect you guys responding so fast. thanks a lot everyone! I got it, I'll check the IO (and probably will go for an SSD like the max IO from ocz).

Answer (score 1):

As others mention, disks are rarely the bottleneck when it comes to bandwidth, but rather in the number of IO operations they can perform per second - commonly called [IOPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOPS).

The IOPS capabilities of your disks will vary according to disk type, cache and the RAID setup you have.

Another thing you may run into is locking. If you have a lot of concurrent access to the same data, especially inside of large transactions, you may see other transactions being blocked - causing no network, CPU nor disk usage while being blocked, just wasted time.

Comment: thanks for the link and the hints. concurrency is not a problem yet, but I'll watch the possible blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the disks. If you are seeking all over the place, the throughput (MB/s) will be low even though the disks are running as fast as they can.

Generic advice: try increasing SQLServer's cache, tune your queries, check that the appropriate indexes exist and are used (and that you don't have too many).